# ExCss parse css with c#

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor, excss

Hello im new at C# and i want to create a own weatherapp with Blazor by using Html CSS and C#, but my problem is, that i dont know how to parse my css code with c#. I will create my logic for the weather app by using c# and not javascript can someone help me?
here is my css file:

```
.backgroundimage {
    background-image: url('../images/sun_background.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;


}

.cloud-background {
    background-image: url('../images/cloud.png');
    /* Füge hier die gewünschten Hintergrundbilderigenschaften hinzu */
}



.card {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 470px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    
    

}
.search{ 
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.search input{
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: #ebfffc;
    color: #555;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
}


.search button{
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: #ebfffc;
    border-radius: 60%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.weather-icon{
    
}
.weather h1 {
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: floralwhite;
}
.weather h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: -10px;
    color: floralwhite;
}
.details {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  
}
.col {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: left;
  
}
    .col img {
        width: 40px;
        margin-right: 10px;
       
    }


.humidity, .wind{
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}







.search button img{
    width: 55%;
}




.center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
   
}

.top-left{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:left 
}
.top-left
{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.margin-top{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

here is my html file:

```
<body class="backgroundimage">

    <div class="card">
        <div class="search">
            <button onclick="window.location.href='/images/SuchIcon.png'"><img src="/images/SuchIcon.png"></button>

         <input type="text" placeholder="Search" spellcheck="false"/>
           

      
        
        </div>
    </div>

   
    <div class="weather"> 
        <div class="center margin-top">
        <img src="images/image1.png" width="200" height="200" style="opacity: 1" class="weather-icon" />
        </div>

       
        <h1 class="temp center margin-top">22°c</h1>
        
        <div class="center">
            <h2 class="city center margin-top">New York</h2>
        </div>

        <div class ="details">
            <div class="col">
                <img src="images/humidity.png"/>
                <div>
                    <p class="humidity">50%</p>
                    <p>Humidity</p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="images/wind.png" />
                <div>
                    <p class="wind">15 km/h </p>
                    <p>Wind Speed</p>
                </div>


            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
    

 



    

</body>
```

here is the old javascript code:

```
const apiKey = "(myapiKey)";
const apiUrl = "(myapiUrl)";

const searchBox = document.querySelector(".search input");
const searchBtn = document.querySelector(".search button");
const weatherIcon = document.querySelector(".weather-icon");



async function checkWeather(city)
{
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl + city + `&appid =${ apiKey}`);
var data = await response.json();
console.log(data);

document.querySelector(".city").innerHTML = data.name;
document.querySelector(".temp").innerHTML = Math.round(data.main.temp) + "°c";
document.querySelector(".humidity").innerHTML = data.main.humidity + "%";
document.querySelector(".wind").innerHTML = data.wind.speed + " km/h";

const body = document.querySelector("body");

if (data.weather[0].main == "Clouds")
{
    weatherIcon.src = "images/suncloud.png";

}
else if (data.weather[0].main == "Clear")
{

    weatherIcon.src = "images/image1.png";
}

        }

        searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            checkWeather(searchBox.value);

        }
```

Look at the logic on my javascript code. i want to have this in c# by using ExCss or u can also use whatever u want, but i need a working solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think you need to parse the CSS? The javascript does nothing of the kind. Also please state where this code will run. Will you make a standalone application or will it run server-side.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i dont know i thought i need to parse the CSS code, do you know how to write my JavaScript Code into a C# code with same logic, cause i need to use c# at my uni. I will run it server-side (http)

Comment: The javascript is working on the DOM (Document Object Model). You don't have a DOM server-side. To generate a response server-side, you need to generate HTML using Blazor, so take the HTML you have and make it into a Blazor page with placeholders for the data you need to show.

Comment: i already use Blazor, the codes ive shown is already in Blazor, my problem is, that i need to use C# for the logic instead of javascript but i dont know the c# code for the same logic like my javascript code. yk what i mean?

Comment: It's not the same logic. You aren't working with a DOM.

Comment: hm ok, but can u help me with the c# code, i  will create a weatherapp and i need a c# code for my html and css, do u have a solution/code? with my css classes.

Comment: can you help me please